# SQL query to get DateDiff of the last two records

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I have a table called Event with eventNum as the primary key and date as a datetime2(7) in SQL Server 2008 R2.  I am trying to get the date of the last two rows in the table and get the difference in minutes. This is what I currently have:

```
Select DATEDIFF(MI, e.date,(Select e2.date from Event e2 where eventNum = (Select MAX(e2.eventNum))))
    From Event e
    Where eventNum = (Select MAX(e.eventNum)-1 from e)
```

and I get this error:

> Invalid column name 'Select eventNum from Event Where eventNum =
>   Select MAX(eventNum) from Event'.

I've changed this 100 times and can't get it to work. Any help?

Answer (score 6):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY eventNum DESC)
        , date
   FROM Event 
)
SELECT Minutes = DATEDIFF(minute, 
           (SELECT date FROM CTE WHERE RN = 2),
           (SELECT date FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1))
```

Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e9c8/17/0

Comment: you could add a `top 1` clause. Now it repeats the result for every row present in the table

Comment: @w0lf: or remove the last `FROM CTE`

Comment: The CTE is like a sledgehammer to crack a nut. You can tell by the query plan it produces. Also, the -1 was for when the answer was wrong, which you've since corrected.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't have to go through the table twice like Tim's answer.

```
select datediff(mi, min(x.date), max(x.date))
from (
    select top(2) *
    from Event e
    order by eventNum desc
) x
```

[image]

Assuming you always have 2 records or more, and the time is monotonously increasing, then the above works.

- If it has only one record, it returns 0 (since max=min=singular record).
- If your times are not monotonously increasing, there's a simple tweak to this query

e.g.

```
select top(1) datediff(mi, x.date, y.date)
from event x
join event y on y.eventnum < x.eventnum
order by x.eventnum desc, y.eventnum desc
```

Comment: Nice, but the `date` may not be in the same order as `eventNum`. If the sign of the dates' difference matters, this is wrong. If it doesn't, it's correct.

Comment: I'm not sure if a millisecond more or less is a key factor for this quesstion when OP just wants a single value, all the more because the order column is the primary key column.